# How to elasticity of the char length in javascript or css?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a sample

```
<h3>How to elasticity of the char length in javascript or css<h3>
<h3>How to elasticity<h3>
```

How to config size of the string if the string is very long

```
<h3>How to elasticity of ...<h3>
<h3>How to elasticity<h3>
```

How to this ideas

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
h3 {
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* magic happens here */
}
```